# How do I construct a minimum spanning forest?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, trees

I realize that a minimum spanning forest in a weighted graph is a spanning forest with minimal weight. Does this mean that I construct it by turning all of the trees into spanning trees?

Comment: What do you mean by "turning all of the trees into spanning trees"? Do you already _have_ some trees rather than a graph? Usually a "spanning forest" would mean the combination of one spanning tree per connected component of the graph.

Comment: No I am not really sure what to do actually. Maybe I should start from the beginning, from the graph G.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a connected Graph to begin with, run either Kruskal's Algorithm or Prim's Algorithm on it to get a minimum spanning tree. In case your Graph is disconnected, do the above mentioned on every connected component to end up with a minimum spanning forest.